# Arithmetic right shift difference between do it once and do through loop

Tags: javascript, bit, bit-shift

I don't know why the result of two arithmetic right are different. Can you shed light on this problem?

```
x=-93242
for (let i=0; i<40; i++) x >>= 1;
// now x is -1

y=-93242
y>>=40;
// now y is not -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript only supports bit operations for upto 32-bits. Since you are trying to shift `y` to the right by 40-bits it's returning `y>>=8` instead.
It will return `-1` if you shift it to the right by 31 bits.
Since `x` is being shifter right only once every iteration, it stays at `-1` because `-1>>=1` will always be `-1`.